# OverlapBoxAll 2d dont detect anything

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection, game-physics

This script should detect the collision with the colliders of the Hurtbox layer (using OverlapBoxAll)but it does not work I have the matrix layer configured well and the variables assigned in the inspector so I do not know what my error is.
pd: The collision ocurs in HitboxUpdate method
My collision layer matrix 2d:

https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/173342-sin-titulo.png

The scene and hierarchy:

https://answers.unity.com/storage/temp/173344-scene.png

The script:

```
public string owner = "-1";
public Vector3 boxSize;
public Vector3 position;
public Quaternion rotation;

public LayerMask mask;
public bool useSphere = false;

public float radius = 0.5f;

public Color inactiveColor;

public Color collisionOpenColor;

public Color collidingColor;
private ColliderState _state;
// ignoreList = ds_List_create()
public float hitStun = 60;
private IHitboxResponder _responder = null;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    HitboxUpdate();


}
public void StartCheckingCollision()
{
    _state = ColliderState.Open;

}

public void StopCheckingCollision()
{
    _state = ColliderState.Closed;

}


void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    // Draw a yellow sphere at the transform's position

    Debug.Log("draw hitbox gizmos");
    CheckGizmoColor();

    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);
    if (useSphere)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(Vector3.zero, radius);         }
    else
    {

        Gizmos.DrawCube(position, new Vector3(boxSize.x * 2, boxSize.y * 2, boxSize.z * 2)); 
    }
}
private void CheckGizmoColor()
{
    switch (_state)
    {

        case ColliderState.Closed:

            Gizmos.color = inactiveColor;
            Debug.Log("Closed");
            break;

        case ColliderState.Open:

            Gizmos.color = collisionOpenColor;
            Debug.Log("Open");
            break;

        case ColliderState.Colliding:

            Gizmos.color = collidingColor;
            Debug.Log("colliding");
            break;

    }

}
public void HitboxUpdate()
{

    StartCheckingCollision();

    if (_state == ColliderState.Closed)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collider cloded");
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log("Collider  open hit");
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(position, boxSize, transform.eulerAngles.z ,mask);
    if (colliders.Length > 0)
    {
        _state = ColliderState.Colliding;
        Debug.Log("We hit something hitbox");
    }
    if (colliders.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Hurtbox>() != null)
            {
                if (colliders[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Hurtbox>().owner == owner)
                {
                    Debug.Log("collider skiped");

                    colliders = colliders.Skip(i).ToArray();
                }
            }
            Debug.Log("Hit " + colliders[i].gameObject.name);


        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
    {
        Collider2D aCollider = colliders[i];
        Debug.Log("Works");
        _responder?.CollisionedWith(aCollider);

    }


    _state = colliders.Length > 0 ? ColliderState.Colliding : ColliderState.Open;


}
public void UseResponder(IHitboxResponder responder)
{
    _responder = responder;

}
```

}
public enum ColliderState
{

```
Closed,

Open,

Colliding
```

}

Answer (score 0):

#### Change

`Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(position, boxSize, transform.eulerAngles.z ,mask);`

#### to

`Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(position, boxSize ,mask);`

Comment: Still not working I tried all the variations of the method apart from you answer : only with mask , mask and angle, only angle  ,changing the mask to everything, changeing the mask to Nothing. I do not know what else to do  ¿Does the layer of the parents matters in any form?

Comment: "Does the layer of the parents matter in any form ?"; No.

Comment: So do you see any other problems? I tried changing the order od the collision matrix and changing the layers of the hurtboxes but nothing changed

Comment: I don't really, But I suggest to check this simple video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4hr7-7ysCY&t=177s
Maybe you'll find something